Anime where mecha is controlled by a boy playing an ocarina
I've been searching for this anime for years, but I can't find it! It was shown in the early 90's on a Chinese channel so I never got the name of it. I can't really remember much but here some stuff that happens in the anime:

The main character is a young boy who plays an instrument, maybe an ocarina
He finds a mecha in a mountain (I think)
When he first finds the mecha he rides on its shoulder and it only walks when he plays the ocarina
All mechas that I remember can be entered from the torso of the mecha (entry point to mecha is through something like an orb?) and be controlled within the mecha
There was also a girl character with pink hair who the main character meets (I think their first meeting is he catches her while she's skinny dipping)
Pink hair girl's brother is on the evil side
All the bad guys have a tear drop on their face


Could it be Yamato Takeru?
One of the descriptions that led me here contains the line: 
"Takeru, a 12-year-old boy from Earth, who happened to discover the buried robot Susanoo and woke it from its million-year-long sleep.
And, as you can see, his friend has pink hair ;)

